# Why doesn't iptables accept IP address as source?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

The command

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -s ! 192.168.178.30 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.178.30:3128
```

fails with

```
Bad argument `192.168.178.30'
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

According to `man iptables` that doesn't make any sense.

`eth1` has `192.168.178.21` and is `up`.

I want to setup a `squid` instance in DMZ as caching proxy following a guide at http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/TransparentProxy-6.html.

I'm running `iptables` v1.4.21 on Ubuntu 15.04 with Linux 4.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 ! -s 192.168.178.30 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.178.30:3128
```

instead of

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -s ! 192.168.178.30 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.178.30:3128
```

The referenced guide isn't editable, so I hope people are stumbling over this.